# AskUbuntu does not recognize my account email

Tags: support

I have been communicating with AskUbuntu for a few weeks on Windows while I brought my Ubuntu internet connection up to speed. Now that I am up and running on Ubuntu, I would like to use my same account, but StackExchange says it does not recognize my email address, clearly displayed in my Windows StackExchange account.

Plus, it has been very difficult to create a new account on this Firefox Ubuntu browser.

Maybe when I post this, I will be up and running because it asks for my email in order to post this question.

Comment: It's been a couple of months with no update. Do you still need help with this?